# The audio player activity playing on Android 14 enters the background and stops after 3 minutes

Tags: android, background, exoplayer

The audio player activity playing on Android 14 enters the background and stops after 3 minutes.

Press the home key on the activity playing with exoplayer to go into the background and stop after about 3 minutes. Then, when you run the app again, it starts playing. It is already requesting to exclude battery optimization. What is the problem?

Comment: Please edit your post to include what type of audio you are playing (local or streamed) as well as your Android Manifest xml file as Android 14 made changes for [media](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#media)

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission in your manifest:

> ```
>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
> ```

Make sure that your service is also stated as:

> ```
> <service .... android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
> ```

in you manifest. See: [for more details](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required).